# Dynamic view panel stop responding

Tags: view, xpages, javabeans

I am developing an application on xpages and I have the following problem:

I use dynamic view panel with customizer bean. The customizer bean is based on the Jesse Gallagher bean available on GitHub (https://github.com/jesse-gallagher/Domino-One-Offs/blob/master/mcl/reports/DynamicViewCustomizer.java).

The problem is that after a few minutes of inactivity in the application, the navigation components (Pager Expand / Collapse, Pager, and PagerSizes) stop responding. The document access link works normally. If a refresh is run in the browser, the navigation components will work again.

If I remove the bean customizer the problem does not happen.

Does anyone know what the cause of the problem is and how to solve it?

Thaks a lot!

Marcus

Comment: What scope is the customizer bean defined as? I am just wondering if application or session timeout is set too low

Comment: The scope is session. Where are the timeouts quoted?

Comment: Timeouts are defined in xsp.properties

Comment: The two timeout properties are empty

Comment: Then it uses the default values which are 30 minutes for both.

Comment: Are you opening other views with the same user in other tabs?

Comment: No, I'm not opening other views with the same user in other tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real cause of the problem was that I was adjusting some component and testing at the same time, without giving a reload in the application in the browser. This causes the behavior of the application to be abnormal. That way if you are testing and concurrently changing something in some component of the application, reload the application in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Put Keep Session Alive controll from Extension Library to your page and set the delay for example to 60s. If this helps, you can change this to higher value.

Comment: It worked!
Do you think I need to increase the delay?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I recommend to increase this value as much as you can. I think it should be enough if the delay value is a bit shorter than timeout .

Comment: Hi. Although  said that you solved the problem, it still has happened, so I'm adjusting the delay. As soon as he had a more precise answer, he marked his response.

Thank you!